# Why all android:textColor are not working and only Black is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

Below code works good in almost all  devices , except `CS_Nexus 6_A` , all the `android:textColor` are not working , all color `(#DB0011 or #6E6E6E )` that displayed  are `BLACK (#000000 )`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:background="@color/beaten_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" ..... (in "
        android:textColor="#6E6E6E" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="red"
        android:textColor="#DB0011" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=") have ....."
        android:textColor="#6E6E6E" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your theme xml file? Its theme specific issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can create `color.xml` file in resources folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="YourColor1">#6E6E6E</color>
    <color name="YourColor2">#DB0011</color>
</resources>
```

And try setting color for texcolor in TextView as below:

```
 android:textColor="@color/YourColor1"
```